# Definining the arquitecture for a CNN model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

Hello im working right now with Keras training a CNN but  i need to define the model
adding the differents layers to transform my 80x60 images. Ive coded the next thing:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, kernel_size=(5, 5),activation='linear',input_shape=(80,60,1),padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

And this is the image ive been following to code it. Is my code correct?
[CNN Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wDd.png)

Comment: use this to see what's going on https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/ and ```model.summary()```, moreover the example you shared is not reproducible because it lacks imports

Comment: this is what thath function gives me: https://i.imgur.com/NegE7XP.png and this is what i need https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wDd.png is it correct? this is the model.summary https://i.imgur.com/t8gTphn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model figure from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wDd.png):
[image]
The correct code for this model would be:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, kernel_size=(5, 5),activation='relu',input_shape=(80,60,1),padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

The image shows `ReLU` activation function but you used `LeakyReLU`, I corrected it.
And also, there would be another `Conv2D` layer at the end, which you missed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw the input shape should be 80x60x1? or should be 44182x80x60 which 44182 is the total images inside?

Comment: @JavierDecenaCastillo You are correct, the `input_shape` should be `(80,60,1)`. If you find this answer helpful, you can highlight that by accepting this as the answer and upvoting. Thank you!